# Слайдинг экранов с помощью ViewPager

Tags: android-viewpager

В моей программе экран приложения разделен на 2 части, верхняя и нижняя. Верхняя часть работает отлично (кнопки и т.п.), а на нижнюю часть я поставил ViewPager, с 4 лаяутами. Если на каждый из этих лаяутов поставить что-то, то при запуске все отображает корректно на каждом лаяуте при переключении, но, если поставить какое-то действие, к примеру - кнопка, при нажатии которой отображается уведомление Toast, то после нажатия эффекта - 0, то есть, кнопка есть, но ничего не происходит. А надо, чтобы это работало. Заранее спасибо.

Код будет ниже, всю информацию (код и т.п.) брал по этой ссылке - https://habr.com/post/131889/

SamplePageAdapter

[image]

Main

[image]

Comment: Нашел решение проблемы, довольно легко. Если надо будет кому ответ, отпишите в пм.

Comment: Здесь нету "ПМ"

Comment: Тексты программ должны быть вставлены текстом, а не снимками экрана